# android videoview scalemode

Tags: android

i set my videoView width & height : "fill_parent"

but i want it to fit screen(full screen , don't keep it original ratio)

how can i scale it?

Answer (score 1):

if you add:

> android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

to your view, it will automatically get "fullscreen" :)