# Android VideoView Proportional Scaling

Tags: android, android-layout, video, android-videoview

In Android's VideoView, is there any way to achieve the same effect as ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP?

That is, I want my VideoView to play the video such that it fills the entire screen without distortion. If the video aspect ratio does not exactly fit the screen's, then it should be cropped rather than distorted.

The following solution will fill the screen, but does not maintain the video's aspect ratio:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927300/1068656

And this solution maintains the video's aspect ratio, but will not fill the entire screen (video is scaled until the longer side hits the screen's edge thereby introducing bars on the side):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855315/1068656

Comment: No, you need to set it manually, you need to do some mathematical calculation with your surface view and video view to adjust the preview size.

Comment: If your app supports only api 14 and above you can use TextureView and then this lib - https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/video-crop

Comment: This solution works for CENTER_CROP OR CENTER_INSIDE https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641686/6082973

Answer (score 17):

In Android's VideoView, here is a simple and easy way to achieve the same effect as `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In Kotlin:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
    val videoRatio = mediaPlayer.videoWidth / mediaPlayer.videoHeight.toFloat()
    val screenRatio = videoView.width / videoView.height.toFloat()
    val scaleX = videoRatio / screenRatio
    if (scaleX >= 1f) {
        videoView.scaleX = scaleX
    } else {
        videoView.scaleY = 1f / scaleX
    }
}
```

In JAVA:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      float videoRatio = mp.getVideoWidth() / (float) mp.getVideoHeight();
      float screenRatio = videoView.getWidth() / (float) 
      videoView.getHeight();
      float scaleX = videoRatio / screenRatio;
      if (scaleX >= 1f) {
          videoView.setScaleX(scaleX);
      } else {
          videoView.setScaleY(1f / scale);
      }
   }
});
```

And this worked for me. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 15):

Although it is too late, but it might help someone else looking for the same problem. The following answer maintains the aspect ratio(videoProportion). The extra part of the 
videoview is cropped by the Phone's view.

```
private void setDimension() {
     // Adjust the size of the video
     // so it fits on the screen
     float videoProportion = getVideoProportion();
     int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
     int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
     float screenProportion = (float) screenHeight / (float) screenWidth;
     android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = videoView.getLayoutParams();

     if (videoProportion < screenProportion) {
         lp.height= screenHeight;
         lp.width = (int) ((float) screenHeight / videoProportion);
     } else {
         lp.width = screenWidth;
         lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth * videoProportion);
     }
     videoView.setLayoutParams(lp);
 }

// This method gets the proportion of the video that you want to display.
// I already know this ratio since my video is hardcoded, you can get the  
// height and width of your video and appropriately generate  the proportion  
//    as :height/width 
private float getVideoProportion(){
  return 1.5f;
}
```

Comment: Really it's working great. No need to find other code. Thanks negi

Comment: There is one problem with this solution - when used in a viewpager, the resized view 'spills over' to the next page, since in portrait a landscape video will set the videoview to be extremely wide. Is there a way to center-crop after resize?

Comment: You can wrap the VideoView in a View with the dimensions of page.

Comment: This resulted in only showing the left/top of the video which didn't suit my needs. To show the center part I added
`videoView.translationX = -(lp.width - screenWidth) / 2f
        videoView.translationY = -(lp.height - screenHeight) / 2f`

Answer (score 3):

`ConstraintLayout` has an attribute `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` for this purpose.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3" <!-- w:h -->
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

See the official documentation for [more details](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is code for  adjust Video UI as per video Size**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```