# Android VideoView how to scale as ImageView scale type fitXY?

Tags: android, scale, android-videoview

I put an ImageView and a VideoView in a RelativeLayout.
The ImageView can be scaled to fill the whole layout by `scaleType="fitXY"`. However, there is no similar scale attribute for the VideoView. By the way, I hide the video control by set `setMediaController(null)` and only the video content displays. Is it possible to scale the VideoView without keep aspect ratio? 
Here is the layout example.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to given static width and height.

Comment: It doesn't work. I try to set `<VideoView        android:layout_width="280dp" android:layout_height="200dp"/>` but get the keep aspect ratio result.

Comment: have you try my ans ?

Comment: I have implemented this solution and it works like a charm : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59069292

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try to put `VideoView` inside `RelativeLayout` and set below properties to show video in full screen :

```
<VideoView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/video"
   android:visibility="invisible"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

**Note :** Please set visibility value based on your requirement.

Comment: @Jones,Glad to help you.

Comment: At this points I am way too afraid to ask why... Works though!

Answer (score 3):

My way is override the **onMeasure** method of **VideoView**

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec),
            getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec));
}
```