# VideoView in ViewFlipper can not be stretched to Fullscreen

Tags: android, android-videoview, viewflipper, android-viewflipper

I want to set fullscreen in `VideoView` which is child of `ViewFlipper` and added programmatically but it does not set as a screen size and it always set as its resolution. I used relative layout out though.

Here is some snippet

viewFlipper.xml

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewflipperSlideShow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="2000"/>
```

Here is code

```
            VideoView postVideoView;
            postVideoView = new VideoView(PostSlideShowActivity.this);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            postVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageURL);
            postVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            postVideoView.setTag(TAG_VIDEO);

            viewFlipper.addView(postVideoView);
```

Comment: ViewFlipper extends FrameLayout, use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);`

Comment: Thanks @EugenPechanec but it ain't worked. I've used this `FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            postVideoView.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);`

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601921/center-crop-an-android-videoview

Comment: I want same functionality of  `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);` for `VideoView` where i can Scale my `VideoView` to total dimension of my mobile screen. But by above code `VIdeoView` is not set to the entire screen. @EugenPechanec

Comment: fit_xy does not preserve aspect ratio, it's going to be stretched. Usually not something you want with video. It can probably be done by adapting what's done in the link above.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help me. I just tried.. Thanks @EugenPechanec